# Shelve module: How to instantly write on memory when using 'deque.append()'

Tags: python, deque, shelve

```
import shelve
from collections import deque
with shelve.open('123', writeback=True) as DATA:
    DATA['TEST'] = deque()
    DATA['TEST'].append(1)
    DATA['TEST'].append(2)
```

This code creates a deque and, after the programm ends, copies it to the file '123.dat' (at least that is what I understand). What I want to do is that after running `DATA['TEST'].append(1)`, the file '123.dat' gets updated, so if you open it you are able to see the deque with the value `1`. Then, after running `DATA['TEST'].append(2)`, the file '123.dat' gets updated again with the new deque but just the value `2` get added, i.e., value `1` is not overwritten and only value `2` is added to the file.

The problem is that in the code that I'm working on handles a fairly heavy deque (over 10gb) and runs in one loop. In each iteration an element is added to the deque, but when closing the program it takes a long time to update the file depending on how long it was running. As it is a neural network I need it to train it for several hours, but I don't want to wait so long every time I want to pause the training.

Does anyone know how to update the file at each iteration only adding the new value obtained?

Comment: That can't be done.  In order to do that, it would have to rewrite the whole file from the beginning.  That's the problem with using a convenience like the shelve.  Perhaps you should use a simpler file format that you can append and flush.

Comment: that couldn't work with `shelve`, which just uses `pickle`. pickle always has to write the entire file, it cannot be updated incrementally like you seem to want. If a simpler format (like a delimited text file) wouldn't work for you, then maybe you would want a dedicated database, relational or otherwise (e.g. mongo) or an in-memory cache like redis.